# Multiple choice questions will respond to anything using simple cmd code when i dont want them to?

Tags: batch-file

I made this code this afternoon and only started to start doing this about a day ago. I can seem to find out why when playing my game I can just press enter on my questions and it will go through to the next level even though I set questions for it.

```
@echo off
title 'Hospital Nightmare'
color 47
if "%1" neq "" (goto %1)
pause
:Menu
cls
echo '1 Start'
echo '2 Instructions'
echo '3 Exit'
set /p answer='Type the number of your option and press enter'
if %answer%==1 goto 'Start_1'
if %answer%==2 goto 'Instructions'
if %answer%==3 goto 'Exit'
:'Exit'
@echo off
echo Happy Dreams
pause
exit /b
:'Instructions'
@echo off
cls
echo 'Instructions'
echo.
echo Self Explanitory you
echo IDIOT!
pause
goto Menu
:'Start_1'
@echo off
cls
echo You awake in a small room
echo that smells like sterilisation
echo and surgical equiptment.
echo.
echo Even though it's small,
echo many things are inside.
echo this is strange?
echo.
echo Screams echo around you
echo and a noise is coming from
echo around the corner!
echo.
set /p answer='Press 1 to find out what it is!'
if %answer%==1 goto 'Fight_1'
:'Fight_1'
@echo off
cls
echo "YOU, YES YOU THERE! DON'T
echo LOOK AT ME LIKE IM STUPID
echo YOU KNOW WHAT I WANT, NOW
echo FIGHT ME!!"
echo.
echo What is this guy going on
echo about??
echo.
set /p answer='would you like to fight or run?'
if %answer%==Fight goto 'Fight_1'
if %answer%==Run goto 'Run_1'
:'Run_1'
@echo off
cls
echo You escape safely!
:'Fight_1'
@echo off
cls
echo "GOOD LUCK"
echo "YOU'RE GONNA NEED
echo IT!"
echo.
echo You wait for thhe first punch
echo.
set /p answer= Type the number 1 and press enter to continue:
if %answer%==1 goto 'Fight_1_Loop'
:'Fight_1_Loop'
set /a num=%random%
if %num% gtr 4 goto 'Fight_1_Loop'
if %num% lss 1 goto 'Fight_1_Loop'
if %num%==1 goto 'Lose_Fight_1'
if %num%==2 goto 'Win_Fight_1'
if %num%==3 goto 'Win_Fight_1'
if %num%==4 goto 'Win_Fight_1'
:'Lose_Fight_1'
@echo off
cls
echo "FIGHT ME EH? YOU
echo GOT NO CHANCE!"
echo.
echo You are knocked
echo out cold! :'(
pause
goto Menu
:'Win_Fight_1'
@echo off
cls
echo "I WAS ONLY JOKING
echo YOU'RE HUGE MAN
echo LEAVE ME ALONE!"
echo.
set /p answer='Would you like to save?'
if %answer%==Yes goto 'Save'
if %answer%==No goto 'Start_2'
:'Save'
@echo off
cls
echo YOU IDIOT YOU CAN'T SAVE
echo I'M NEW TO THIS AHAHAHA!
:'Start_2'
@echo off
cls
echo That guy was crazy.
echo Now where am I? and what did
echo he want with me?
echo.
echo This place is an old hospital
set /p answer='Before we keep going what's your name?'
if %answer%=="Meerkat" goto 'Hallway'
:'Hallway'
@echo off
cls
echo You turn left to into a
echo hallway to find that it
echo is very long and wide.
echo.
echo LIKE MY D*CK!!!
echo.
echo "Now is not the time to
echo joke narrator."
echo.
echo Ok
echo.
echo Well umm...
echo You turn left...
echo To find...
echo A...
echo F*CK IT! You find
echo a HOBO OCTOPUS!!!
echo.
echo "Dude wtf."
echo.
echo "Ok I'll do it."
echo.
echo YESS! Let the battle begin!
echo.
set /p answer='Will you fight this fight?'
if %answer%==Yes goto 'Fight_2'
if %answer%==No goto 'Scene_1'
:'Scene_1'
@echo off
cls
echo YOU DON'T WANT TO FIGHT
echo AN OCTOPUS?
echo.
echo WHAT ARE YOU? OCTOPUSSY?
pause
goto Menu
:'Fight_2'
@echo off
cls
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable to blank as you get the prompt:

```
:Menu
cls
echo '1 Start'
echo '2 Instructions'
echo '3 Exit'
set /p answer='Type the number of your option and press enter' || SET answer=NO_ANSWER
if %answer%==NO_ANSWER GOTO Menu
if %answer%==1 goto 'Start_1'
if %answer%==2 goto 'Instructions'
if %answer%==3 goto 'Exit'
GOTO Menu
```

The final GOTO Menu also ensures that the value that was inserted was not just nonsense, for example `sdhghdhf` or some other invalid value. It will act as the "default" case.

Just copy this kind of structure to every "decision" and it should work fine.